# why redefine type variable in Predef.scala?

Tags: scala

[image]

Why are these type aliases and vals introduced in `Predef`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things that are in `Predef` are automatically imported. In Scala, you can write

```
val mySet : Set[String] = Set( "cat", "dog", "poop" )
```

without having to first write

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Set
```

Note that the declaration I wrote above might have been written equivalently as

```
val mySet : Set[String] = Set.apply( "cat", "dog, "poop" )
```

On the right-hand side of the equals sign, the word `Set` refers to a singleton object. We can only call methods on objects (whether singletons or instances of classes). We can't call methods on types. Somehow, we must have autoimported the name of an object `Set`. This is what the Predef declaration

```
val Set = immutable.Set
```

does.

If you are a Java programmer, you can think of a `val` declaration that just points to an object that would otherwise require the use of an import or a much longer name as being the equivalent of `import static`.

The `Set[String]` after the colon and before the equals sign is a type annotation. In this context `Set[String]` is a type. An object is not a type. If all we had declared in `Predef` were the `val`, our declaration could not compile. We would have been saying that `mySet`'s type is a some particular object, but a type is very different from an object, a type is a description of a category to which an object may belong.

To let `Set` also serve as a type, we need the type alias

```
type Set[A] = immutable.Set[A]
```

If you are a java programmer, this functions similarly to a nonstatic `import` of a type name. (Scala has imports as well, but they must be scoped to a specific block or file. `type` aliases in Predef are available to all Scala files, so it does much more than an `import` of the type would do.)

The package `scala.collection.immutable` contains both an object, declared as

```
object Set{ ... }
```

and a type, declared as

```
trait Set[A]{ ... }
```

If we want to be able to use both the object (with its useful factory methods) and the type (the compile-time description of the objects our factory creates), we need to make both of them, object and type, available to our code. The two lines (for `Set`) that you quote above do precisely that. (And the other two lines do precisely the same for `Map`.)

Answer (score 0):

These types and vals just make importing unnecessary, I believe.

The vals are assigning the companion objects into the vals - again, getting rid of an import.

I suspect they are done in this odd way to avoid a circular compile-time dependency between Predef.scala and Map/Set.scala, but I'm only guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of `Predef` is to avoid explicit qualifications and import statements.  From the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Predef$):

> The `Predef` object provides definitions that are accessible in all
>   Scala compilation units without explicit qualification.
>
> `Predef` provides type aliases for types which are commonly used, such as the immutable collection types `scala.collection.immutable.Map`,
>   `scala.collection.immutable.Set`, and the
>   `scala.collection.immutable.List` constructors
>   (`scala.collection.immutable.::` and `scala.collection.immutable.Nil`).

This way, you can refer to `Map` without having to explicitly qualify or import `scala.collection.immutable.Map`.